# Understanding the Mid() in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am having an issue with the MID() function in VBScript
Here are some sample lines I do have in my text.

```
::UNm DL=254 DH=409.3 DS=16.2
::UNm DL=254.3 DH=409.3 DS=16.2
::UNm DL=254.32 DH=409.3 DS=16.2
::UNm DL=254.325 DH=409.3 DS=16.2
```

I am reading a txt file, and I wish to extract the value contained in between DL= and DH=

Now the value as you can see will vary.

dataline = InFile.ReadLine

```
Mid(Dataline, Instr(Dataline,"DL")+3, Len(Dataline) - (InstrRev(Dataline,"DH=")-Instr(Dataline,"DL")+3))
```

and also tried

```
Mid(Dataline, Instr(Dataline,"DL")+3, Len(Dataline) - (InstrRev(Dataline,"DH=")-Instr(Dataline,"DL")-3))
```

Seems the results vary from one time to the other. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting but using `Split()` to break on each line then use it on each line splitting on space will get you closer then any of this.

Comment: You may want to explain it detail what you mean by *vary from one time to the other*

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple ways to fetch the desired value:

### Using Mid method

```
Dim line : line = "::UNm DL=254.325 DH=409.3 DS=16.2"
MsgBox getValueByMid(line)
Function getValueByMid(strLine)
    Dim sDelim, sPos, eDelim, ePos
    sDelim = "DL="
    eDelim = "DH="
    sPos = InStr(1,strLine,sDelim,1)
    ePos = InStr(1,strLine,eDelim,1)
    getValueByMid = Mid(strLine,sPos+Len(sDelim),ePos-(sPos+Len(sDelim)))
End Function
```

---

### Using Regular Expression

```
Dim line : line = "::UNm DL=254.325 DH=409.3 DS=16.2"
MsgBox getValueByRegex(line)
Function getValueByRegex(strLine)
    Dim regex, matches 
    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Multiline = True
    regex.Pattern = "\bDL=(.+?)DH="                         'captures all the contents between DL= and DH= and stores it in Group 1
    Set matches = regex.Execute(strLine)
    If matches.count > 0 Then
        getValueByRegex = matches(0).submatches(0)          'matches(0) - means first match; submatches(0) - 1st group of the current match
    Else
        getValueByRegex = ""
    End If
End Function
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vVoXjU/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - matches a word-boundary
- `DL=` - matches `DL=`
- `(.+?)` - matches 1 or more occurences of any character, as few as possible and captures this submatch in Group 1 of the match
- `DH=` - matches `DH=`.

---

### Using split method

```
Dim line : line = "::UNm DL=254.325 DH=409.3 DS=16.2"
MsgBox getValue(line)
Function getValue(strLine)
    getValue = Split(Split(strLine,"DL=")(1),"DH=")(0)
End Function
```

---

**Output:**

[image]